# Conditional replacement r across columns. gsub vs. mutate_all?

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements, dplyr

I'd like to change certain characters across columns to a different character. For instance,

```
mockdata<- data.frame(a = paste(rep(letters[1:4],10), rep(1:2, 20), sep = ""), b = paste(rep(letters[4:1],10), rep(1:3, len= 40), sep = ""))
```

Here, I'd like to chance all appearing `d1` and `d2` to `d`. When I use `gsub` as below , it works.

```
mockdata2 <- apply(mockdata,2,function(x) gsub("d1|d2",'d',x))
```

However, using `mutate_all` below does not work and I'd like to know what goes wrong in this. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

```
mockdata <- mockdata %>% mutate_all(funs(recode(., "d1" = "d", "d2" = "d")))
```

Comment: It seems to work fine? Can you give us your expected output?

Comment: Works fine for me too. Is there an error that you are getting?

Comment: @tyluRp the `mutate_all` edited output seems to be doing what the OP wants. This will confuse everyone and I think we should wait for OP to provide more details about the problem

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan apologies, reverted

Comment: Ah, sorry! I should have tried my codes using mockdata before posting the question. The actual data frame for which I've tried the codes had other columns that do not contain the values that I tried to recode -- "d1" and "d2" in this example -- and columns with logical values. As you said, mutate_all works fine after selecting only the columns that have the values to recode. Thanks!